# Adjusting the Potentiometer into Acquired Value

Tags: potentiometer

The goal is to find the base current, collector-emitter voltage- and the base-emitter voltage for each of the values.. My problem is, how am I gonna adjust the potentiometer into 0.2 , 0.4 up to 2.0 for me to get the required parameters .. I provided an image for a better view.

[image]

[image]

Comment: LOL I've found the "how do I turn a potentiometer" question. No actually I didn't. Reading your comments to the answer... you wanted this in a specific simulator... and you didn't even mention that in the question. In simulators that is done by parameter sweeps by the way.

Answer (score 2):

What's the problem?

You turn the potentiometer while observing the collector current until the current equals the defined values 0.2, 0.4, 0.6...

You'll find that as you turn the potentiometer one way the current increases and goes down when you turn it the other, so just get the desired current then don't touch it while you make the voltage measurement. Then do the next setting/

When you have adjusted the collector current to each of those values you measure Vbe and Vce with a volt meter.

Comment: I'll be measuring those required parameters using multsim. My only problem is on how to adjust it on multisim .. I already know how to get those.. Just the way on how to adjust into 0.2 - 2.0

Comment: I a simulator you may need to do it by trial and error, you could calculate the value to get a close value.

Comment: Got it . Just as simple instruction as you provided. Appreciate it.

Comment: I just did what you just have told me .. adjusting the potentiometer to get the 0.2 mA but at 100% , my collector current is 0.675 (least current) .

Comment: Can't get the 0.2 and 0.4 mA anymore since the least current I've got was 0.675 mA at 100% . What am I gonna do?

Comment: The simulated transistor has an HFE that is too large to use just a 1megohm pot.  Change the pot to have a max value of 5 megohm.

Comment: Without changing the value of the 1 mega ohm resistor, what possible transistor can be use?

Comment: You might try a 2N2222 - HFE has a very wide range and in general should not be relied upon.  Multisim could have almost any value for HFE. Does Multisim allow you to change the HFE in the transistor model?

Comment: So you mean to say that at 1Mohm resistance, the transistor 2N2218 is not accurate to be use for me to get the the value of 0.2 at 100% and 2.0 at 0% .

Comment: The Multisim model has too high a HFE to work with the components - I would recommend changing the value of the pot.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the potentiometer to get the desired collector current, then record the other values as required.

If you don't understand the assignment, you should ask your instructor, lab assistants, or other students.

Comment: I mean I'm gonna measure it using multisim .. how am I gonna do it there . what's the percentage for?